# how to apply here singleton pattern to prevent creating object of fom3 again and again

Tags: c#

```
public Form fr;
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

       fr = Form1.ActiveForm;

       fr.Hide();

       Form3 fr1 = new Form3(fr);
       fr1.Show();
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a singleton? You've got a class-level reference to a `Form`, and calling `Hide` doesn't destroy the form. If you instantiate the class-level variable properly, then you shouldn't need to create a new instance. Just call `Show` against the reference.

Comment: As Kenneth said, singleton is unnecessary here. Construct it once and you can `.Show()` and `.Hide()` as many times as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't.

You cannot use the singleton pattern with UI components because a Windows Form encapsulates a Win32 hWnd window, which will need to be disposed of eventually, and you cannot resurrect a window, you have to recreate it, which is contrary to the singleton pattern.

Furthermore, the Windows Forms designer needs a public default constructor. Even if you could use singleton you would need to disable the private constructor every time you edit your form in the designer.

Assuming your project has no consumers, a better idea is to change your form to `internal` and just track every instantiation yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create `Form3` as singleton (I think you can't do that) but you need to instantiate it only once. For instance you could use something like this:

```
public Form fr;
Form3 fr1 = null;
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

       fr = Form1.ActiveForm;

       fr.Hide();
       if(fr1==null)
        fr1 = new Form3(fr);
       fr1.Show();
}
```